# Form returning Numerical answer on the form

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, microsoft-teams

How can I create a form which returns the answer on the form itself in either SharePoint or Microsoft Teams?

It should calculate a numerical answer from a prespecified formula based on the inputs on the form.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to modify the form with Power Apps. It will provides you a way to set the field value with a formula based on your requirements.

Here is an example using Power Apps to update with a button click:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Setting-a-field-value-with-click-of-a-button/td-p/171661